Django Project CORS error after deployment
I got Pyton Django project and my project work on local server but when i deploy on server i got this error.I used IIS Manager for deployment.Other DB connection must be work because i can reach other APIs.By the way my user is superuser.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://website.websites.com:8000/integration/sync' from origin 
'https://website.website.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-                
Allow-Origin'header is present on the requested resource.
And here is my API;POST https://website.website..com:8000/integration/sync net::ERR_FAILED 500 
(Internal Server  Error) 

By the way OTher API are working without problem
I search about error and they suggest me to change setting.py but under below is my settings;
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True 
MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

 I use for deployment IIS may be its about it.
 So they said that its about Autontication 

IIS
I tried every combination but it still doesnt work,

Are you getting the same error without cors enabled? Maybe you can also try adding the following configuration to the web.config file to enable cors.
<system.webServer>  
  <httpProtocol>  
    <customHeaders>  
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />  
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS" />  
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, soapaction" />  
    </customHeaders>  
  </httpProtocol>  
</system.webServer>  

If this doesn't work, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

<system.web>            <identity impersonate="false" />            <authentication mode="Windows" />            <authorization>                 <allow users="?" />            </authorization>             <system.web>    `
May be we shuold change something there,  when i apply your setting website complety lost :(``

You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Unfortunely there  is no error message just show me status 500,i think is about web config confugirations

You can follow this link about how to enable failed request tracking: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7.

There is one update:When i trigger the function which triggered by API by cmd console its working but it takes 8 minutes more or less,but when i send request on Frontend its end 2 min and sent me 500 http error code.I couldnt find anything except it

In addition to the 500 error, do you get any other error messages? Is there any relevant error message in the failed request tracking log or Event Viewer?

it show me no error ,i got something btw all my failed request max 1.7 min it can be about time limit

Actually its not about CORS in my opinion there is an error on django server on IIS so it makes it collapse and that collapse make this CORS error.

time.sleep(120) when i add it beginning of function its give me same error.I add  even if i added all applications pool and site i still got same error
